# RegEx in Notepad++ to replace text in files with some exclusions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have multiple text files which have various xpaths in their content. I want to use Notepad++ to add one new node in these xpaths, but there are some exceptions where I dont want to do it and due to them I'm struggling with preparing the right RegEx statement.

The goal is to add **FpML** node in xpath after **allocation** node with below exceptions:

1. If **allocation** is preeceded by **CRD_Structured**
2. If node after **allocation** is **FT_Extension**

Note that **allocation** is repetable node and therefore in these text files it might be denoted with specific index in [].

Examples:

1. allocation[Out1]/@fpmlVersion **-->** allocation[Out1]/FpML/@fpmlVersion
2. allocation[Int1]/trade **-->** allocation[Int1]/FpML/trade
3. allocation[Out1]/FT_Extension **-->** no change
4. pathString="allocation[]" **-->** no change
5. CRD_Structured/allocation[FindAllocOut1]/TS_ORDER_ALLOC **-->** no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not try and find one regex/replace to achieve this. Instead I would make the change in several steps. In brief, I would (in steps 2 and 3 below) insert a marker string into `allocation` for all cases that should not be changed then (at step 4) insert the wanted text and finally (step 5) remove the marker string.

In more detail.

1. Choose a marker string that does not occur within the text. The string `!!!` is used below.
2. Regex replace `(CRD_Structured/a)(llocation)` with `\1!!!\2`.
3. Regex replace `(a)(llocation\[\w+\]/FT_Extension)` with `\1!!!\2`.
4. Replace `(a)(llocation\[\w+\]/)` with `\1!!!\2FpML/`.
5. Replace `!!!` with nothing.

Note that step 4 also inserts the marker string. This is to prevent multiple insertions of `FpML/`.

Item 4 in the question is not clear. It may be that an addition to steps 2 and 3 is needed. This addition would regex replace `^(a)(llocation\[\w*\])$` with `\1!!!\2`. This assumes that the path string is the complete line.

Comment: This is great, thank you! All went fine. Now I need to spend a little more time to fully understand syntax you used there :)